# How to pass an URL to a <a href="">

Tags: php, html

I'm still new to php and I've made a script that checks the language of the website and if it's English set's the button link to an english page and else to another page.

Here goes:

```
<?php 
                            $link1 = "http://www.uvt.ro/ro/accesibilitate/";
                            $link2 = "http://www.uvt.ro/en/accesibilitate/";
                            $url = "";
                            if($_SESSION["lang"]->lang!="ro"){
                                $url = $link2;
                            }
                            else {
                                $url = $link1;
                            }
                            ?>

<a href=".$url.">Button</a>
```

It's supposed to be simple, I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd [echo](http://php.net/echo) the `$url` like so:

```
<?php 
$link1 = "http://www.uvt.ro/ro/accesibilitate/";
$link2 = "http://www.uvt.ro/en/accesibilitate/";
$url = "";
if ($_SESSION["lang"]->lang != "ro") {
    $url = $link2;
}
else {
    $url = $link1;
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo $url;?>">Button</a>
```

You can condense the code to this using the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
<?php 
$link1 = "http://www.uvt.ro/ro/accesibilitate/";
$link2 = "http://www.uvt.ro/en/accesibilitate/";
$url = ($_SESSION["lang"]->lang != "ro") ? $link2 : $link1;
?>

<a href="<?php echo $url;?>">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo $url in  tag.

```
<a href="<?php echo $url;?>">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href=".$url.">Button</a>
```

replace with:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Button</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="<?=$url?>">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

[See the page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

```
<?php  
    $test = $_GET['p'];
 ?>
 <a href="diffdir/<?php echo $test ?>">Test</a>
```

or

Try like

**HTML in PHP :**

```
echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>Link</a>";
```

Or even you can try like

```
echo "<a href='$link_address'>Link</a>";
```

Or you can use PHP in HTML like

**PHP in HTML :**

```
<a href="<?php echo $link_address;?>"> Link </a>
```